# Как изменять расстояние между блоками?

Tags: html, css

Помогите, пожалуйста, как изменять расстояние между элементами, не затрагивая остальные (как например эту кнопку '-')

[image]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.shopping-cart {
  width: 750px;
  height: 423px;
  margin: 80px auto;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
  border-radius: 6px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.title {
  height: 60px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E1E8EE;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  color: #5E6977;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.item {
  padding: 20px 30px;
  height: 120px;
  display: flex;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  border-top: 1px solid #E1E8EE;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E1E8EE;
}

.buttons {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 60px;
}

.delete-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  Cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}

.delete-btn {
  width: 18px;
  height: 17px;
  background: url("delete-icn.svg") no-repeat center;
}

.description span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #43484D;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.description span:first-child {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.description span:last-child {
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-top: 8px;
  color: #86939E;
}

is-active {
  animation-name: animate;
  animation-duration: .8s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: steps(28);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    background-position: left;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: right;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: right;
  }
}

.quantity {
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 150px;
}

.quantity input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 32px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #43484D;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#minus-btn,
#minus-btn1 {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #E1E8EE;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#plus-btn,
#plus-btn1 {
  margin-top: 2px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #E1E8EE;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:focus,
input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

#price,
#price1 {
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 83px;
  padding-top: 27px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #43484D;
  font-weight: 300;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="item" th:each="el : ${session.cart}">
  <div class="image">
    <img th:src="${session.cart['img']}" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="description">
    <span th:text="${session.cart['name']}"></span>
    <span th:text="${session.cart['item_size'] != null} ? ${session.cart['item_size']}"></span>
    <span th:text="${session.cart['color']}"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="quantity">
    <button id="plus-btn" type="button" name="button">
      <img src="plus.svg" alt="" />
    </button>
    <input id="cart_quantity" th:value="${session.cart['quantity']}" />
    <button id="minus-btn" type="button" name="button">
      <img src="minus.svg" alt="" />
    </button>
  </div>
  <input type="number" id="price" th:value="${session.cart['price']}" readonly/>
  <div class="buttons">
    <form th:action="'/cart/remove'" method="post">
      <button class="delete-btn" type="submit"></button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

при delete-btn{ margin-left - кнопка '-' спускается вниз

Comment: сделайте пример таким как на картинке, что ви прикрепили. В текущем примере ничего не разваливаться.

Answer (score 0):

Решение простоe: кнопкам + и - установить значение absolute